# Stores.persistentKeyValueStore() changlog topic retention period

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I could not find from documentation or any other sources about retention period of changelog topic of `Stores.persistentKeyValueStore()`.

Does `Stores.persistentKeyValueStore()` create changlog topic with retention period forever?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Stores.persistentKeyValueStore() creates a topic with cleanup.policy=compact, which means topic with log compaction enabled. Such topics will have retention period -1, meaning the messages will never be deleted.

Comment: Messages with matching keys do get deleted with `cleanup.policy=compact`. Retention settings don't apply at all for compacted topics

Comment: I agree, just used different language but meant the same. Messages get deleted as per compaction rules (new key/value replaces old key/value). Messages will not be deleted based on the time when it was added in the topic - effectively giving forever retention period for messages (except new key overriding old).